# Should I create an index on a foreign key for selects?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

In postgresql, given these tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE departments(
   id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   department_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE employees(
   id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   employee_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   department_id INT REFERENCES departments
);
```

does creating an index on `employees (department_id)` improve performance on `SELECT`'s, like `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE department_id = 123`, supposing 1K departments and 10K employees ?

While I could answers on the benefit of indices on foreign keys for `DELETE`'s, I'm not sure if and why the reasoning applies to `SELECT`'s.

Comment: The query in your question can clearly benefit from the index. In general, you can never answer the question based only on the table definitions, but you need to know the queries that should be fast.

Comment: Yes, the index will improve the performance of that specific query.

Answer (score 1):

At least if I create the index and I generate some random data:

```sql
CREATE INDEX ON employees (department_id);

INSERT INTO departments(department_name)
SELECT md5(random()::text) FROM generate_series(1, 1000);
INSERT INTO employees(employee_name, department_id)
SELECT md5(random()::text), floor(random() * 1000 + 1)::int FROM generate_series(1, 10000);
```

I can see that the index is used:

```
> explain select * from employees where department_id = 100;
                                        QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on employees  (cost=4.35..32.11 rows=9 width=41)
   Recheck Cond: (department_id = 100)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on employees_department_id_idx  (cost=0.00..4.35 rows=9 width=0)
         Index Cond: (department_id = 100)
(4 rows)

> explain select * from employees join departments on employees.department_id = departments.id where department_id = 100;
                                           QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=4.63..40.50 rows=9 width=78)
   ->  Index Scan using departments_pkey on departments  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=37)
         Index Cond: (id = 100)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on employees  (cost=4.35..32.11 rows=9 width=41)
         Recheck Cond: (department_id = 100)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on employees_department_id_idx  (cost=0.00..4.35 rows=9 width=0)
               Index Cond: (department_id = 100)
(7 rows)
```

The answer is thus: **yes**, I should probably always create an index on foreign keys.

I also noted that, with little data (< 10 rows in both tables), the index is not used (`Seq Scan`).

Comment: The answer is "yes" and you have answered it yourself.